# Chart.js performance issue on iPad

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, chart.js, chart.js2

I have created a small game using chart.js and canvas. However I have only one canvas to create the whole game so I wanted to draw some images too on the canvas.
Due to this the games works superb on windows as well as android phone but I'm facing performance issue on the iPad. Can anyone assist me in achieving my task keeping only one canvas

I have recreated the scenario in the below pen

https://codepen.io/sushantipte48/pen/voLxyW

```
    var _ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext("2d")
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = 300;
    canvas.height =200;
    var bg = new Image();
    bg.src = 'https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/vibrant-pink-watercolor-painting-background_53876-58930.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg';
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
    var graphImage;
    var mainData = [],
      points = [],
      x = 0,
      y = 0,
      config,
      currentMax = 20,
      slope = 1;
    config = {
      "data": {
        "datasets": [{
          "type": "line",
          "data": mainData,
          "backgroundColor": "#ff0000",
          "borderColor": "#ff0000",
          "fill": false,
          "lineTension": 1,
          "borderWidth": 1,
          "pointRadius": 0
        }]
      },
      "options": {
        "legend": {
          "display": false
        },
        "animation": {
          "duration": 0
        },
        "responsive": false,
        "maintainAspectRatio": false,
        "scales": {
          "xAxes": [{
            "display": true,
            "type": "linear",
            "ticks": {
              "beginAtZero": true,
              "min": 0,
              "max": 100
            }
          }],
          "yAxes": [{
            "display": true,
            "stacked": true,
            "ticks": {
              "padding": 10,
              "beginAtZero": true,
              "min": 0,
              "max": 100
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    };
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);

    setInterval(addingData, 1000/24);

    function addingData() {  
      mainData.push({x:x,y:y});
      x += 0.1;
      y = slope * x;
      if (x % 10 === 0) {
        points.push(y);
      }
      config.data.datasets[0].data = mainData;
      myChart.update();
      var img = new Image();
      img.src = canvas.toDataURL('image/png',1.0)
      img.onload = function () {
      graphImage = img;
        drawCanvas();
      };
    }

    function drawCanvas(){
      _ctx.drawImage(bg,0,0,600,400)
      _ctx.drawImage(graphImage,0,0,300,200);
    }
```